# wait to leave page until ajax is done

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically, I am sending a `$.POST()` when an  element is clicked. this element brings the user to a different page, and the POST request is not going all the way through. If i step through it slowly the script gets ran, however.

How can i make the page wait until the script has run until it navigates away from the page? or is there a different issue here? Sort of new to AJAX

```
$('.ad-link').on('click', function() {
    $.get('http://easyuniv.com/php/clickPP.php?id='+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

and then clickPP.php is just a simple SQL query that i have verified to work.

Thanks

Comment: see   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321360/making-functions-wait-until-ajax-call-is-complete-with-jquery

Comment: the code you specified above doesn't send a **POST** ; it sends a **GET** request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a callback for this, like so:

```
$('.ad-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url_to_redirect = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(
        'http://easyuniv.com/php/clickPP.php?id='+$(this).attr('id'),
        {},
        function(return_data){  // callback function, wait till request is finished
            // use the return_data if you need it
            location.href = url_to_redirect; // redirect the user
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: does the callback function have to have something in it? I tried it with the callback function empty, and it is doing the same thing as before.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to. I just added it there to note that you could do something, if you wanted to

Comment: hmm, still only working if i step through in the console, but not if i just click the link

Comment: I have added a `e.preventDefault()` now. This should stop the link from going somewhere till you ask it to leave in the callback